# Getting an error in android SMS code in createFromPdu() method

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) obj);

//In the above code, I get a line on 'createFromPdu()' method.
//So should i add any dependencies or any other solution. Please help me

Which dependencies should I add or change?

Comment: That particular overload is deprecated. The current version takes a second argument for the format: `createFromPdu(byte[] pdu, String format)`. What you should change depends on whether you should be using that method to begin with. If you're just looking at incoming messages, you should probably be using [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) instead. It will handle the PDU decoding for you, and return an array of `SmsMessage`s. If that's not what you're doing, you'll need to tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this was introduced for Android Marshmallow to support "3gpp" for GSM/UMTS/LTE messages in 3GPP format or "3gpp2" for CDMA/LTE messages in 3GPP2 format.

this is simple example, I hope it will help you

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "";

    if (myBundle != null)
    {
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");

        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                String format = myBundle.getString("format");
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
            }
            else {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage += " : ";
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            strMessage += "\n";
        }

        Log.e("SMS", strMessage);
        Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i am still getting the same in this code

Comment: @AyushVaze gimme your error message